# Multi-label classification from single-label train dataset with deep learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, classification, multilabel-classification

I am trying to build a deep-learning model for 1D univariate time series classification. I have four different classes in my train dataset. Each class has the same amount of train data. I also have a test dataset that I am not using for training. The problem is in my test dataset, there are multi-label examples. As an example, my train dataset looks like this:

```
[3. 3. 6. 7. 8. 2. 1. 1. 1. 3.] [1 0 0 0]
[7. 6. 4. 4. 6. 8. 3. 4. 6. 4.] [0 0 1 0]
[5. 5. 1. 7. 6. 3. 6. 1. 4. 2.] [1 0 0 0]
[1. 1. 5. 5. 7. 3. 4. 6. 4. 4.] [0 0 0 1]
[4. 2. 3. 1. 7. 2. 4. 1. 1. 7.] [0 1 0 0]

#and my test dataset is like this:

[ 4.  3.  3.  2.  5.  2.  3.  7.  2.  0.] [1 0 1 0]
[ 3.  3.  3.  1.  6.  3.  4.  4.  1.  3.] [0 1 0 0]
[ 2.  1.  7.  8.  4.  5.  0.  4.  6.  6.] [1 1 0 0]
[ 5.  1.  9.  5.  3.  4.  1.  8.  1.  8.] [1 0 0 0]
[ 2.  1.  7.  6.  2.  2.  9.  1.  9.  3.] [1 0 1 0]
```

Currently, my model uses sigmoid, binary cross-entropy, and adam.
it is sufficiently good for finding at least one of two labels, but not them together.
How can I achieve this using a CNN or RNN?

so far what I tried is:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(values, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

num_classes = len(np.unique(np.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0)))
input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]

enc = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
enc.fit(np.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0).reshape(-1, 1))
y_train = enc.transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
y_test = enc.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

#some model...

output_layer = Dense(units=num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(dense_layer)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
nb_epochs = 500

if earlystopping:
 
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=50, restore_best_weights=True)
 
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epochs,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[early_stopping])

predictions = model.predict(test_values) #test_values are different than X_test.
```